# Piskei teshuvos on resting elbows on a sefer

Tags: jewish-books

Can someone please translate this Piskei Teshuvos:

> **פסקי תשובות אורח חיים סימן קנד**
>
> ומי שמניח אצילי ידיו על הספר דרך לימודו, ג"כ אין זה דרך בזיון כיון שבתום לב וכהרגל העוזר לו להבין תלמודו בתנוחה כזו עושה זאת, וכמו"כ אלו המתנמנמים על        הספר תוך כדי לימודם א"צ להקיצם, כיון שהוא דרך לימודו

Comment: To downvote without comments is not fear

Comment: He says that since he doesn't make this by contempt, because he makes this naturally, this posture help him to understand. Moreover, people who drowse on the books are not a problem

Answer (score 1):

(gave it a shot with some help from [google translate](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20translate&oq=google%20translate&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.4041j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

**פסקי תשובות אורח חיים סימן קנד**

> ומי שמניח אצילי ידיו על הספר דרך לימודו, ג"כ אין זה דרך בזיון כיון שבתום לב וכהרגל העוזר לו להבין תלמודו בתנוחה כזו עושה זאת, וכמו"כ אלו המתנמנמים על
>   הספר תוך כדי לימודם א"צ להקיצם, כיון שהוא דרך לימוד

**Piskei Teshuvos Orach Chaim, siman 154:**

> and one who rests his elbows on his *sefer* while learning, this is also not a disgrace since this is being done with a sincere heart and as a habit to help him understand his learning by in such a position, and similarly one doesn't need to wake up those who fall asleep on their *sefer* while they're learning since this isn't abnormal for people who are learning.

Comment: I think Google made quite a few mistakes here. Rather than going through line by line in the comments, I edited with what I think is an improvement and rolled it back so that you can choose which revisions you agree with

Comment: @ba thanks a lot! yep "noble hands" didn't really sound right- rolled back to the first revision you made which seems to read the clearest